# "Task<PeopleUser> doesn t contain a definition for Role and no extensions method "Roles" accepting a first argument of type Tasl<PeopleUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

can somebody help me? I want to implement edit user' role in Identity 3, but when i write this, i have an error:

> Task doesn't contain a definition for Roles and no
>   extensions method "Roles" accepting a first argument of type
>   Task

Here is the controller code

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(PeopleUser user, string role)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        var oldUser = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
        var oldRoleId = oldUser.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId;
        var oldRoleName = _db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == oldRoleId).Name;

        if (oldRoleName != role)
        {
            _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, oldRoleName);
            _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
        }
        _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

Comment: What, .Net platform, Using statements and assembly references do you use?

Comment: core 1 with EF 7 and Identity 3 , using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TraficC.Model;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` the `Task` before you can use the `TUser` object.

```
// Note that the signature has async and Task<ActionResult>.
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Edit(PeopleUser user, string role)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        var oldUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id); // Note the await keyword.
        var oldRoleId = oldUser.Roles.SingleOrDefault().RoleId;
        var oldRoleName = _db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == oldRoleId).Name;

        if (oldRoleName != role)
        {
            // I've added await here as well...
            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, oldRoleName);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role);
        }
        _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

[`FindByIdAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497542(v=vs.108).aspx) returns `Task<TUser>`, which means that you need to "unwrap" it, before accessing the `TUser` object. You unwrap it by using the [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) keyword.

```
public virtual Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(
    TKey userId
)
```

So to clarify your example:

```
// Create the task. Note the difference between the types of oldUserTask and oldUser.
Task<User> oldUserTask = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
// Await the task.
User oldUser = await oldUserTask;
// Now you can do something with oldUser.
oldUser.DoStuff();
```

More about asynchronous programming [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

> In .NET Framework programming, an async method typically returns a
>   `Task` or a `Task<TResult>`. Inside an async method, an `await` operator is
>   applied to a task that's returned from a call to another async method.
>   You specify `Task<TResult>` as the return type if the method contains a
>   return statement that specifies an operand of type `TResult`. You use
>   `Task` as the return type if the method has no return statement or has a
>   return statement that doesn't return an operand.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works but i have some problem because when i make debug in Roles of user founded, i see null, but in interface when I write razor syntax @user.isinrole...it works and in table ASP.NetUsers appear